# how can i run command line commands on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line

Here is my rake task in Rails 4 app below.

```
 task :traceroute_ip => :environment do
     puts "start.........................."

     ip = IpAddress.first
     ip_address_output =  `traceroute -q 1 -n google.com`
     ip.update_attributes(traceroute_output: ip_address_output)      

  end
```

I have error on this line  below which is working correctly locally in my Rails app rake task.

```
        ip_address_output =  `traceroute -q 1 -n google.com`
```

The error is

```
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake: No such file or directory - traceroute
```

This below command will run on any ubuntu terminal

```
         traceroute -q 1 -n google.com
```

How i can install "traceroute" on heroku?

```
  sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use  [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi) to combine [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) and your ruby buildpack.

Create a `.buildpacks` file:

```
$ cat .buildpacks
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

And an `Aptfile` file containing your packages:

```
$ cat Aptfile
traceroute
```

Then you need to set *heroku-buildpack-multi* as your custom buildpack:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

**Update**: Try to run `traceroute.db` instead of `traceroute`:

```
$ heroku run traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com
Running `traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com` attached to terminal... up, run.6887
traceroute to google.com (74.125.228.68), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.16.231.221  0.116 ms
 2  10.135.67.1  2.812 ms
 3  100.70.9.1  2.154 ms
 4  100.70.9.40  2.344 ms
 ...
```

Comment: i have done as you describe above. Add two file .buildpack text file with  these contents   https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby and APtfile file with this traceroute. Then push to heroku below is my all output when deploying

Comment: After this operation, 176 kB of additional disk space will be used.
       Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe traceroute amd64 1:2.0.19-3 [44.6 kB]
       Fetched 44.6 kB in 0s (658 kB/s)
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing traceroute_1%3a2.0.19-3_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby

Comment: In above comment you can see traceroute have installed below is my rake 

task :traceroute_ip => :environment do
  puts "start.........................."
  puts `traceroute -q 1 -n google.com`  

end

it giving me error "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake: No such file or directory - traceroute"

any help please?

Comment: Updated my answer. Try to run `traceroute.db` instead of `traceroute`

Comment: I see this is "heroku run traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com"  running fine. But  i want to run this " `traceroute -q 1 -n google.com` " in my rake task. i tried this `traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com` with this command "heroku run rake traceroute_ip --app openreverseip" but same error.

Comment: Try to change ``ip_address_output =  `traceroute -q 1 -n google.com` `` to ``ip_address_output =  `traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com` `` in your rake file.

Comment: In above comment i say i have tried `traceroute.db -q 1 -n google.com`  in rake task. but same error.

Comment: This error is "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake: No such file or directory - traceroute.db"